# Trocar cor de imagem ou imagem em loja virtual

Tags: jquery

Colegas.

Tenho visto em algumas lojas virtuais que existe o recurso de mudar as cores do produto. Como eu faria para que ao clicar em uma determinada cor, o produto fosse alterado sem refresh? veja um modelo: lapupa.com.br/539sl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim, tendo em conta que isto obviamente não é o mesmo produto nem cores, mas a lógica será esta:

```js
const prod_colors = {blue: 'https://cdn.mensagenscomamor.com/resize/400x225/content/images/int/imagens_de_deus.jpg', green: 'http://cdn.mixme.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/disney5.jpg', red: 'https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQJ8oMypN2S5RyM1S9zKxO3AOBc1UNT_EanYOIRYWK1evZVaj5'}
    
    for(var color in prod_colors) { // adicionar dinamicamente as cores que temos à disposição ao nosso select
       $('.colors').append('<div style="background-color: ' +color+ '" data-image="' +prod_colors[color]+ '"></div>');
    }
    $('.colors div').on('click', function() {
      var img_cor = $(this).data('image');
      $('.img_dinamic').prop('src', img_cor);
    });
```

```css
.colors div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <img class="img_dinamic" src="https://cdn.mensagenscomamor.com/resize/400x225/content/images/int/imagens_de_deus.jpg">
    <div class="colors">
      
    </div>
    <br>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Miguel, mas na verdade gostaria de algo parecido com esse modelo: http://www.lapupa.com.br/539sl

Comment: @Fox.11 na verdade a lógica é a mesma mas vai ser no click de divs em vez de estar num select, podias ter posto essa especificação na pergunta, agora não tenho muito tempo para fazer essa alteração, talvez mais tarde consiga

Comment: Obrigado Miguel. Funcionou.

Comment: @Fox.11 de nada, ainda bem